# Django timezone logic and Generic View in urls.py raise an error, but is it the view, the field or me?

Tags: django, generics, datetime, view

My blog is built with Django 1.4.1. The blog is nothing special, mostly like the examples in the Django tutorials and books. The datebase is PostgreSQL. I tried to use as many generic stuff as possible including the Sitemap framework. Unfortunaly, the generated sitemap shows a timezone issue.

The field "pub_date" in the Blog entry model has the type DateTimeField. The timezone of the blog is 'Europe/Amsterdam'. If I enter the date and time in the Blog admin interface, then the column in the database has the correct value (e.g. 2012 JUL 10 00:00 admin interface => 2012 JUL 09 22:00 UTC PostgreSQL). The function Blog.get_absolute_url() does produce /2012/07/09/slug. I expect the UTC date (which is fine with me)

My *urls.py* is like all the examples.

```
info_dict = {
    'queryset': Blog.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
    }

url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'django.views.generic.date_based.object_detail', info_dict),
```

(Note: I am using the function based generic view here, but I tried also the class based view. Both views do produce the same issue).

The issue is: Every Blog entry can be found with the value from get_absolute_url(), but not the ones with a different date for local time zone, and UTC (e.g. 2012 JUL 10 00:00 local => 2012 JUL 09 22:00 UTC). I do get a "404", and - when running with runserver - the error is *RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2012-07-09 23:59:59.999999) while time zone support is active*.

My search on the net did show many posts for Django timezone issues. Most of them do relate to the month format for date based archives. I am using the latest Django release 1.4.1 to have most fixes. I did not find any examples in tutorials or books for date_based.object_detail, or DateDetailView relating to timezones. At the moment, I am in doubt about the correct way to go.

Probably not a good idea

1. I can loose the 'time-zone' awareness (USE_TZ = False), but that is ignoring the problem
2. I can change *get_absolute_url()* to produce the date in local time zone (in this example 2012/07/10/slug) but then I am mixing up database format and user format

Don't know if this is a good (or feasible) idea

1. Do something with the dictionary info_dict to inform the generic view that pub_date is in UTC format. I could not find a way to do that
2. Do something with the dictionary to change the datetime format (e.g. pub_date.date) but this gives a syntax error. Also, Django docs say that DateField and DateTimeField are supported for generic views

What is a good way to go? Focus on the pub_date to convert to a DateField, work on the view to accept the DateTimeField, switch from a generic view to a home-made view, or something else?

What is the most common way with Django to solve this issue?

Comment: For now, I'm switching to the object id. I changed blog.get_absolute_url() to return the id (self.id). In urls.py I use django.views.generic.DetailView. The regular expression find the id in the url and named it <pk>. This all works fine.

Comment: My next step is using the Date based archive generic views. I see many blogs, notes, comments and so on, about the time-zone awareness of Django. I still don't understand if this does not work, or if I don't understand this stuff. So more experimenting is required

Answer (score 3):

I have been wrestling with this exact issue for a few hours now.  The crux is that my get_absolute_url logic results in a UTC response, but the DateDetailView expects the URL to match the local timezone.

My solution to this is the following for get_absolute_url:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
# Other model code here

def _get_absolute_url(self):
    local_pub_date = timezone.localtime(self.entry.pub_date)
    return ('%sblog_detail', (), {
        'year': local_pub_date.year,
        'month': local_pub_date.strftime('%m'),
        'day': local_pub_date.strftime('%d'),=
        'slug': self.slug
    })
get_absolute_url = models.permalink(_get_absolute_url)
```

This appears to work for my purposes.  All of my users are in the same timezone, though, so it may not be appropriate for sites with a more diverse userbase.

-PT

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue in that my get_absolute_url is showing the next date instead.  I have searched everywhere and can not find anything to help with the latest Django version.  My only suggestion to you would be to have the date and time be separate fields in the database.

Comment: Check your database. I do use Postgresql. As documented, the column pub_date (is datetime) has the UTC and the difference. My get_absolute_url does always show the UTC.

Comment: I don't wanna switch from datetime to date & time. Technically everything works fine, it's just that no standard has been choosen for this issue. For now, my switch to object id is fine.

Comment: I checked mysql setup and it is putting it in UTC but my timezone for the software is PDT. I tried when it was still the same date for PDT and UCT but when it shows via the template then it is wrong on the display. In my research I found someone that said to do this and it fixed on of the other date/time issues I had... I am still too new with Django to fully understand why this fixed this issue:   date_list_utc = blogpost.objects.filter().dates('blog_pub_date','month')
  date_list = []
  for datetimeobj in date_list_utc:
    dateobj = datetimeobj.date()
    date_list.append(dateobj)